# Changing the values of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df, pasting row which I am concerned with.

```
                                        plan_benefits                                              value
0                    What is the overall\ndeductible?                  $2,000 Individual / $4,000 Family
```

I want to change this to something like below-

```
 plan_benefits                                              value
0                    medical_deductible_single                  $2,000
1                    medical_deductible_family                  $4,000
```

**Update -:** 
Removed individual and Family from `value` column.

I am doing something like below-

So basically I am fetching that row, getting the values, creating a dict and appending that back to my original dataframe. I can remove the previous row once this is done.
Is it okay to do like this ?

```
 medical_deductible_single = 0
    medical_deductible_family = 0
    for index, row in df_rep.iterrows():
        if row['plan_benefits'] == 'What is the overall\ndeductible?':
            list = row['value'].split('/')
            medical_deductible_single = list[0][:7]
            medical_deductible_family = list[1][:8]

    deductible_dict = {'plan_benefits': ['medical_deductible_single', 'medical_deductible_family'], 'value': [medical_deductible_single, medical_deductible_family]}
    deductible_df = pd.DataFrame(data= deductible_dict)
    df_rep = df_rep.append(deductible_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

one way to do this

```
data = pd.DataFrame(df.value.str.split("/",expand=True).unstack().reset_index(drop=True)).rename({0:'value'},axis=1)

data['plan_benefits'] = 'medical_deductible_' + data['value'].str.split().str[1].map({'Individual':'single', 'Family':'family'})

##print(data[['plan_benefits','value']])
```

---

```
               plan_benefits               value
0  medical_deductible_single  $2,000 Individual 
1  medical_deductible_family       $4,000 Family
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a working solution:

```
import pandas as pd    

elements = df.value.values[0].split('/')[1] # separates the 'value' entry into two

col_values = []
col_values.append([i for i in elements])
col_values.append(['medical_deductible_' + i for i in ['single','family']])

columns = ['plan_benefits', 'value']
df = pd.DataFrame([{colums[i]:col_values[i] for i in range(len(columns))}])
```

note that is not very general as your question was very particular (you don't give information about the other rows in the data, are they all similar to the one you wrote in the question?). You will have to tweak this code a bit to make it work for other different rows.